# MP3::Tag - UTF-16 unrecognized BOM

Tags: perl, encoding, mp3

I am writing a small perl script to re-tag my MP3 collection based on the filenames.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use MP3::Tag;
use File::Find;

MP3::Tag->config(write_v24 => 1);
my $dirpath = "../MP3s/";
finddepth(\&wanted, $dirpath);
sub wanted {
    unless (-d $_) {
        my ($track,$artist,$title);
        if(($track,$artist,$title) = ($_ =~ m/(\d+) - (.+?) - (.+)\.mp3$/g)){
            #handle songs with a track number
            my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($_) or die $!;

            $mp3->track_set($track);
            $mp3->artist_set($artist);
            $mp3->title_set($title);
            $File::Find::dir =~ m/.*\/(.*)/;
            $mp3->album_set($1);
            $mp3->update_tags();
            $mp3->close();
            print "$track - $artist - $title\n";
        } elsif(($artist,$title) = ($_ =~ m/(.+?) - (.+)\.mp3$/g)){
            #handle songs without a track number
            my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($_) or die $!;

            $mp3->track_set("");
            $mp3->artist_set($artist);
            $mp3->title_set($title);
            $mp3->update_tags();
            $mp3->close();
            print "$artist - $title\n";
        }
    }   
}
```

This works fine, but there are some files which make the script crash with this error:
`UTF-16:Unrecognised BOM 3100 at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Encode.pm line 175.`

What causes this error? The filename doesn't have special characters like german umlauts (ä,ö,ü).

How can I resolve this problem or skip such files?

Comment: Incomplete answer: Something passed a string that didn't start with a BOM to `decode "UTF-16"`. Since `decode` has no way of knowing whether the string is encoded using UTF-16le or UTF-16be without the BOM, so you must specify the exact encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start by adding [`use Carp::Always`](https://metacpan.org/module/Carp%3a%3aAlways) that will give you a stack trace showing you which statement in your own program was fatal.

Comment: This shows the stacktrace down to `File::Find::finddepth('CODE(0x29830e0)', '../MP3s/') called at mp3tag.pl line 11` but not further. But it's a neat module.

Comment: @Demnogonis: Then you must replace your `wanted` subroutine with an empty stub and start adding to it until you reproduce the exception.

Comment: Ok, I reproduced it. It seems, that MP3::Tag is unable to set the tags because of a bad file encoding. Are there better methods than `eval{}` to skip these files?

Comment: So it crashes out on `MP3::Tag->new`? `eval` is the only way unless there's something built into the module specifically for this, or you can check the validity of the files in some other way beforehand. I highly recommend you use the `Try::Tiny` module's encapsulation of `eval`, as otherwise establishing the error condition can get very messy.